# How to determine if there is at least one cell that contains a formula in a range?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a series of columns:

```
=A1+B1
2
=1+2
```

I want to output the value "formula is present" if at least one of those cells is a formula.
How to do this in a single formula, without having to create an additional column where I would use the `ISFORMULA` function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IF e.g. `A1:A10` is the range you want to check then in e.g. `A11` you could put

```
=OR(ISFORMULA(A1:A10))
```

and accept it as an array formula (`ctrl+shift+enter` to enter).

This could of course be modified to something like

```
=IF(OR(ISFORMULA(A1:A10)), "formula is present")
```